# Cannot attach debugger to chrome in React-native with unauthorized error

Tags: react-native, debugging

I am a newbie to React-native Development. I am able to run my app on android emulator by changing port to 8088 as my organization is using McAfee in port 8081. Everything is working fine but i am not able to debug my app in chrome. Whenever I press 'Debug JS remotely' I am getting unauthorised error in console and debugger-ui is not using react-native developer tools. I tried a lot and found some links to the problem.
[This link addresses the problem but I am not getting how to pull the code from react-native master branch.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12095)

It has been two days and I am still struggling to find the solution. I will be thankful if someone helps me out there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "ALLOW-CONTROL-FLOW-ORIGIN" from chrome extention.
Uninstall build from device or Simulator/Emulator
Run Again

Hope it will be fixed.